# Is Fragment.onStop() guaranteed to be called?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

From the table at this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

we can see that an Android Activity is not killable until after onStop() has been called (for Honeycomb and beyond).

Do we have the same (documented) guarantee for Fragments?

Would greatly appreciate someone pointing me at documentation where it is clearly stated.

Edit: As has been pointed out [Fragment.onStop] is *generally* tied to Activity.onStop of the containing Activity's lifecycle.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onStop()

But this doesn't tell me that Fragment's onStop() is guaranteed (at least not to the same level of clarity that the Activity documentation gives.) Is there anywhere that Fragment.onStop() guarantee is explicitly stated?

Edit 2: Based on the discussion below, we are now debating whether Activity.onStop() is guaranteed (it seems safe to assume that if not, then neither is Fragment.onStop guaranteed). I have moved the question about Activity.onStop to a new thread: [Is Activity.onStop() guaranteed to be called (API 11 +)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395169/is-activity-onstop-guaranteed-to-be-called-api-11).

It seems to me necessary, but not sufficient, that Activity.onStop is guaranteed to be called for Fragment.onStop to be also guaranteed.

Answer (score 4):

`onStop()` fragment is no longer visible to the user either because its activity is being stopped or a fragment operation is modifying it in the activity.

This is generally tied to Activity.onStop of the containing Activity's lifecycle.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onStop()

In Low memory, it is not guaranteed for both activity and fragment will call onStop() method

> Note that this method may never be called, in low memory situations where the system does not have enough memory to keep your activity's process running after its onPause() method is called.
>
> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#Fragments

Comment: The word 'generally' in that sentence doesn't give me quite the level of confidence that I need - it infers that the onStop on Fragment may not be guaranteed.

Comment: @Villa User navigates backward or fragment is replaced/removed onStop is called

Comment: The situation I am most concerned about is when the Fragment's process is stopped under low-memory conditions. Under these conditions Activity.onStop() is guaranteed to be called but Activity.onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called. My question aims to discover if those same guarantees hold for Fragment. From a pretty careful read of the documentation I can't find this guarantee stated anywhere for Fragments. I am not particularly concerned by what normally happens under various navigations, I understand those well enough. I am concerned with explicitly documented run-time guarantees.

Comment: @Villa In Low memory, it is not guaranteed for both activity and fragment will call onStop() method. also check my updated answer

Comment: That's interesting. Your update to your answer seems to contradict my first link from the original post. In the 'Killable?' column of that table it says that an Activity is only killable after onStop (from Honeycomb). So which one of those two is the real truth.

I had previously read the part "Note that this method may never be called..." that you quoted above to mean that: since pre-honeycomb doesn't guarantee onStop() then the method documentation says it may never be called. Now I'm unsure.

Comment: The source code seems to agree with Fahim that onStop may not be called in low memory situations:  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onStop%28%29

Comment: @Jahnold: That link does indeed back up what Fahim is saying. I'm still finding it hard to reconcile it with this text from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle:

"Starting with Honeycomb, an application is not in the killable state until its onStop() has returned... and allows an application to safely wait until onStop() to save persistent state."

Comment: Here nowhere it is mentioned about low memory

Comment: is the onDetached or onViewDestroyed more reliable in the Fragment to know that you can not use it's context anymore?